# Window: command get current disk speed in/out

Tags: powershell

[image]

I want to get current disk info `Read Speed` and `Write Speed` not `max speed I/O`

like image above, read speed = 0; write speed = 8.8MB/s

Please, anyone can show me a command can get that info.

Comment: Have you tried [performance counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-5.1) yet?

Answer (score 0):

Just to begin with, this class will give you everything you need that you desire to have:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process
```

But my preference is

1) [powershell-is-king-Measure-disk-performance-for-iops-and-transfer-rate](https://deploymentbunny.com/2014/04/02/powershell-is-kingmeasure-disk-performance-for-iops-and-transfer-rate/)

2) [2 Functions for IO](http://andrewmorgan.ie/2012/11/monitoring-storage-disk-queues-and-io-with-powershell/)

Hope it helps